# How can I move listview below MDToolbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

As you can see in the screenshot the Listview's top items are mixing with mdtoolbar. I want to display below the MDtoolbar.I tried changing the pos_hint property in MDList in kv code. but it not moving. How can I move it below? is there any way to stick it below the toolbar without pos_hint

**.py file**

```
class ListApp(Screen):
    built = BooleanProperty(False)

    def build(self):
        if self.built:
            return
        self.built = True
        self.popup = Popup(title='Calculating Stoploss', content=Image(source='please_wait.gif'))
        self.popup.open()
        threading.Thread(target=self.actual_build).start()

    def actual_build(self):
        end = datetime.today().date()
        start = end

        i = 0
        fl = len(file.index)
        try:
            for index in range(fl):

                for index in range(1):
                    columnSeriesObj2 = file.iloc[:, 0]

                    df = web.DataReader(columnSeriesObj2.values[i],'yahoo', start, end,retry_count=3)
                    print(df.head())
                    Objname = file.iloc[:, 2]
                    columnSeriesObj = df.iloc[:, 3]
                    columnSeriesObj1 = file.iloc[:, 1]
                    ObjStoploss = file.iloc[:, 3]

                    cp = iter(columnSeriesObj.values)
                    pp = iter(columnSeriesObj1.values)
                    pp1 = next(pp)
                    cp1 = columnSeriesObj.values[0]
                    sl = columnSeriesObj1.values[i] - (columnSeriesObj1.values[i] * (ObjStoploss.values[i]/100))

                    if cp1 <= sl:
                        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_loss, Objname.values[i], str(cp1), str(sl)))
                        i=i+1
                    else:
                        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_profit, Objname.values[i], str(cp1), str(sl)))
                        i=i+1
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Check your Internet connection")
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout!!!!...Check your Internet connection")
        except KeyError:
            pass

        except:
            pass
            # print("Something went wrong")
        print("Done")
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def add_loss(self, name, close_price, stop_loss, dt):
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source='loss.png')
            items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Alert sale " + name, secondary_text='Close price: '+close_price,
                                                tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + stop_loss)
            items.add_widget(image)
            self.ids.list_view.add_widget(items)

    def add_profit(self, name, close_price, stop_loss, dt):
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source='profit.jpg')
            items = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Chill " + name,
                                                secondary_text='Close price: ' + close_price,
                                                tertiary_text='Stoploss: ' + stop_loss)
            items.add_widget(image)

            self.ids.list_view.add_widget(items)



# class WindowsManager(ScreenManager):
#     pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(ListApp(name='Stoploss_ip'))



class run1(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("stopl.kv")
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run1().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
<ListApp>:
    name: 'Stoploss_ip'
    orientation:'vertical'
    on_enter:root.build()
    MDToolbar:
        title:'Stoploss'
        type: "top"
        md_bg_color:229/255,33/255,101/255,1
        left_action_items: [["back button.png", lambda x: root.back()]]
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        elevation:8

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: list_view
            pos_hint: {'y':3.0}
```

here is link for stoploss.csv [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lq_DCGjuhhm4_k0j9VkD_xr4OyoqHoS/view?usp=sharing)

here is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Toolbar:

    ScrollView:
```

Comment: Heya, @Xyanight! Is this the full answer? Could you please check that the code is correct and add some explanation?

Comment: @Vivi. No its just a structure. not a full code. He is just pointing me to the right direction. If want the full code.. see my question and In kivy code--> <ListApp> just add MDBoxLayout.

Comment: @Rushabh Patil, the issue is that even though you understand the answer, someone else reading this in hopes of solving a similar problem but perhaps a bit different, or a person a bit more inexperienced than you, might not understand. A short explanation is usually encouraged. That said, since I have no idea at all about this topic, I will leave that to you guys to decide :)

Comment: @Xyanight. i think Vivi is right. I am updating your answer with brief explanation